# Pulling .NET Solution in VS 2017 Community from GIT

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

A basic question here, but after moving to a new laptop I decided to give VS 2017 Community a whirl (after working extensively with VS 2013 Ultimate).

So I install VS 2017 community successfully and had no issues with the install whatsoever.

However, when I pull my GIT solution (all files are pulled from the repository successfully), the new VS installation isnt doing the following;

1. picking up connection strings stored in the web.config and displaying them in the server explorer?
2. doesn't pick up a startup project (and doesn't allow me to select from solution explorer or from the dropdown presented next to the set start up option, which only gives me the option for the current document).
3. doesn't allow me to publish my webapi? (Again no option to even setup a publish option when I right click on my webapi for instance).
4. no option to build the solution.

I assume this is a simple setup option, but cannot find any reference on how to fix it. Can anyone guide me as to what I'm doing wrong here?

For reference my VS info is;

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017  Version 15.2 (26430.14)
>   Release VisualStudio.15.Release/15.2.0+26430.14 Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version 4.7.02046
>
> Installed Version: Community
>
> Visual Basic 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA932 Microsoft Visual Basic
>   2017
>
> Visual C# 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA932 Microsoft Visual C# 2017
>
> Visual C++ 2017   00369-60000-00001-AA932 Microsoft Visual C++ 2017
>
> Visual F# 4.1   00369-60000-00001-AA932 Microsoft Visual F# 4.1
>
> Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   8.6.00404.2
>   Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.0.30503.0 ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017   5.2.50303.0 For additional
>   information, visit https://www.asp.net/
>
> Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   15.0.30209.0 Azure App Service Tools
>   v3.0.0
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.9 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> Cookiecutter   3.0.17114.1 Provides tools for finding, instantiating
>   and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.
>
> JavaScript Language Service   2.0 JavaScript Language Service
>
> JavaScript Project System   2.0 JavaScript Project System
>
> JavaScript UWP Project System   2.0 JavaScript UWP Project System
>
> KofePackagePackage Extension   1.0 KofePackagePackage Visual Studio
>   Extension Detailed Info
>
> Merq   1.1.17-rc (cba4571) Command Bus, Event Stream and Async Manager
>   for Visual Studio extensions.
>
> Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9 Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2017 - v2.9.50131.1
>
> Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting
>   Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0 Microsoft Visual Studio VC
>   Package
>
> Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   Mono.Debugging.VisualStudio Support
>   for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.
>
> Node.js Tools   1.3.50417.1 Adds support for developing and debugging
>   Node.js apps in Visual Studio
>
> NuGet Package Manager   4.2.0 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
>   For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.
>
> Python   3.0.17114.1 Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates,
>   debugging, interactive windows, and other support for Python
>   developers.
>
> Python - Django support   3.0.17114.1 Provides templates and
>   integration for the Django web framework.
>
> Python - IronPython support   3.0.17114.1 Provides templates and
>   integration for IronPython-based projects.
>
> Python - Profiling support   3.0.17114.1 Profiling support for Python
>   projects.
>
> R Tools for Visual Studio   1.1.30523.1233 Provides project system, R
>   Interactive window, plotting, and more for the R programming language.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.61702.140 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> TypeScript   2.2.2.0 TypeScript tools for Visual Studio
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Unity   3.1.0.0 Visual Studio Tools for Unity
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows Apps   15.0.26430.06 The
>   Visual Studio Tools for Universal Windows apps allow you to build a
>   single universal app experience that can reach every device running
>   Windows 10: phone, tablet, PC, and more. It includes the Microsoft
>   Windows 10 Software Development Kit.
>
> Xamarin   4.5.0.486 (fec6f88) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.Android SDK   7.3.1.2 (9dbc4c5) Xamarin.Android Reference
>   Assemblies and MSBuild support.
>
> Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   10.10.0.37 (ad35de4) Xamarin.iOS and
>   Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Comment: Did you look at the `Output` and `Error` windows? If anything shows there, please add it into the question. Did you get a Project Conversion Report; anything of note in there? Most likely your old project uses a tool or library that is not present on your new laptop (e.g. Telerik, DevExpress, ...). PS I think the long list of versions is irrelevant and only clutters the question.

Comment: When I initially pulled the project there were no errors I saw (is there anywhere I can check for these?) also there didn't appear to be any conversion of the project (would this be required at the end of the day I am just continuing a .net 4.6 project). Also I'm not using any devexpress or telerik conponents  intellisense is working as well. Also, I'll update and remove all the vs info bar basic versioning.

Comment: If there is a hidden folder in the solutions folder named .vs delete it.  close visual studio and reopen the project.  This sometimes fixes issues building web sites.